# Комбинации сумм слагаемых

Tags: sql

Прошу помочь с запросом, пытаюсь получить сумму желаемого числа 17404142.26
из таблицы docs c полями id, doc,docsum. В итоге получаю не все суммы числа. нужна одна из подходящих комбинаций.
Т.е. пример желаемая сумма 10, ее можно собрать из значений 1+2+3+4 = 10.
Комбинаций может быть много, но нужна одна которая дает эту сумму. Или не быть вообще, нужно точное совпадение.
Пытаюсь делать таким запросом:

SQL

```
SELECT id,doc,docsum
FROM docs t
WHERE docsum+COALESCE((SELECT SUM(docsum) FROM docs WHERE docsum<t.docsum),0) <= 17404142.26
ORDER BY docsum
```

Итог: (61 запись, только сумма 1029341)

```
0.01
1.73
10002.9
10005.6
10017.59
100205.85
1002104.89
10026.85
1002676
100434.03
10044.83
100466.68
100474.56
100480.61
100488.2
1005352.96
1006.83
100605.31
100674.7
100678.94
100764.06
100769.27
100769.64
10087.06
100913.46
1009559.56
10097.74
10112.35
1011368.38
101157.33
10121.15
10121.76
1012195.78
101311.54
1013165.62
101429.65
101430.69
1015008.48
10152.72
1015400.29
101581.51
101647.72
101675.06
1019.39
101990.06
10205.46
1021.03
1021.58
1021317.57
1021377.42
1021492.97
102245.47
102295.15
102325.74
1024.73
1024068.58
10243.56
102458.45
102526.26
1025288.6
10258.8
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос пример исходных данных (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO) и требуемый результат. PS. А сколько реально записей в `docs`? Вы понимаете, что это полнопереборная задача, 2^N? сервер скорее всего просто загнётся на ней.

Comment: какие решение тогда проблемы чтобы сервак не упал? Примерно 10 000 тыс.

Comment: Это задачка на динамическое программирование, которую надо решать на клиенте. MySQL только поставит исходные данные, для удобства можно сортированными.

Answer (score 0):

Пример решения задачи с использованием рекурсивного CTE. Диалект MySQL 8+

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT id, CONCAT_WS(',', id) kit, val summ 
         FROM test
         UNION ALL
         SELECT test.id, CONCAT_WS(',', test.id, cte.kit), cte.summ + test.val
         FROM cte
         JOIN test ON cte.id > test.id
         WHERE cte.summ + test.val <= @sum )
SELECT kit, summ 
FROM cte
WHERE summ = @sum;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f90a126cee6598ce68b00985e73cef49

Для справки - в данном fiddle CTE из 9 значений исходной таблицы генерируют 232 выходные записи (а теоретически максимальное количество - 511). С увеличением количества записей в таблице количество генерируемых записей растёт ну очень быстро...

Answer (score 0):

```
    Использую базу SQlite необходимо получить только один любой вариант, в вашем запросе
```

используете CONCAT_WS данной функции нет в Sqlite, подскажите как переписать.

Моя таблица:
CREATE TABLE docs (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
number TEXT NOT NULL,
total REAL NOT NULL
)

Comment: WITH RECURSIVE
temp_docs AS (SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', number) kit, total summ 
         FROM docs
         UNION ALL
         SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', docs.number, temp_docs.kit), temp_docs.summ + docs.total
         FROM temp_docs
         JOIN docs ON temp_docs.number > docs.number
         WHERE temp_docs.summ + docs.total <=  17404142.26)

select kit,summ form temp_docs
where summ =  17404142.26; Ошибка ошибка синтаксиса, что делаю не так?